# using nth-last-child css in ul

Tags: html, css

Can you help me with styling of last link in this ul.

```
#DeltaTopNavigation ul.root.ms-core-listMenu-root.static a {
    vertical-align: middle !important;
    padding: 0 35px;
    border-right: 1px #dadada solid;
}
<div id="DeltaTopNavigation" class="ms-core-navigation" role="navigation">
     <div class=" noindex ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox">
          <ul class="root ms-core-listMenu-root static">
               <li class="static">
                    <a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" href="/" accesskey="1"></a>
                    <ul class="static">
                         <li class="static selected">
                              <a class="static selected menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-core-listMenu-selected ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" href="/AboutPGTU"></a>
                         </li>
                         <li class="static">
                              <a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" href="/Docs"></a>
                         </li>
                         <li class="static">
                              <a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" href="/Services"></a>
                         </li>
                         <li class="static">
                              <a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" href="/Ratings"></a>
                         </li>
                    </ul>
               </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

I try to use

```
#DeltaTopNavigation ul.root.ms-core-listMenu-root.static a:nth-last-child(1) {
    border: 0 ;
}
```

but it's set border:0 to all links. How can i do this only for last one?

Comment: The reason why it selects all links is because you are always selecting the last link in each of the list items, while you wish to select the last list item its link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to use `last-child` on the `li` instead of `nth-last-child()` on the `a`.

```css
#DeltaTopNavigation ul.root.ms-core-listMenu-root.static a {
  vertical-align: middle !important;
  padding: 0 35px;
  border-right: 1px #dadada solid;
}
#DeltaTopNavigation ul.root.ms-core-listMenu-root.static li ul.static li:last-child a {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="DeltaTopNavigation" class="ms-core-navigation" role="navigation">
  <div class=" noindex ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox">
    <ul class="root ms-core-listMenu-root static">
      <li class="static">
        <a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" href="/" accesskey="1"></a>
        <ul class="static">
          <li class="static selected">
            <a class="static selected menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-core-listMenu-selected ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" href="/AboutPGTU"></a>
          </li>
          <li class="static">
            <a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" href="/Docs"></a>
          </li>
          <li class="static">
            <a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" href="/Services"></a>
          </li>
          <li class="static">
            <a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" href="/Ratings"></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
#DeltaTopNavigation ul.root.ms-core-listMenu-root.static li:last-child a {
    border: 0;
 }
```

You need to add the :last-child to the li as currently its selecting the last a tag within all the li's. So setting it to the li will mean its selecting the a tag within the last li.

Here is a [link for more info](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/l/last-child/)